# Animate div when content is added

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, transition

I'm building a little live search function for a website. Everything is working great, but I'd like to be able to animate the results div. So when the div is being  filled, give the div a little transition. Now it's all done very abruptly.

```
<div class='search-result-container'>           
    // for loop here: 
    <div class="search-result">
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( post_permalink() ); ?>">   
            <div class="inner-search-result">
                <h2><?php the_title();?></h2>
                <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $ID, 'full' ); ?>">
            </div>
        </a>    
    </div>
    // end of for loop
</div>
```

The search-result-container is the class that actually expands in size. The search-result class is actually in a for-loop to write all the posts to the page. I think I need some more javascript for this, but I have never really worked with javascript animations. Any thoughts?

Comment: So What you tired to do?, Can you have a snippet?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jQuery`

First need to verify if the div is empty:

```
  function divEmpty( el ){
      return !$.trim(el.html())
  }
  if (divEmpty($('.search-result-container'))) {
      // console.log('its empty nothing happens')
  } 

  else { 
  //do animation
  }
```

A syntax for animation is as follows:

```
$(selector).animate({params},speed,callback);
```

You can search for a desited animation and add it in the `// do animation` area